# would multiplying a co-variance matrix by the inverse of a variance matrix generate a beta matrix?

Tags: portfolio-management

I was multiplying the popular calculation w' * Σ * w and got the idea of generating a beta matrix. multiplying Co-variance by inverse variance. Would this work? generating the beta of each asset to the portfolio consistently? Or would this generate something useless?

Comment: Probably I don't understand what you propose. But generally when you multiply a thing by the inverse of that thing you just get the Identity.

Answer (score 2):

The ordinary least squares regression [estimate of beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_regression_model) of $y$ to $x$ is given by
$$
\beta = \frac{\textrm{cov}(x, y)}{\textrm{var}(x)}.
$$

In your case, you want to calculate the beta of asset $i$ to your portfolio $p=\sum_j w_j x_j$.
$$
\beta_i = \frac{\textrm{cov}(x_i, p)}{\textrm{var}(p)} = \frac{\textrm{cov}(x_i, \sum_j w_j x_j)}{w^T\Sigma w} = \frac{\sum_j w_j\textrm{cov}(x_i, x_j)}{w^T\Sigma w}
$$
For the last step, we use the property of [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties) that $$\textrm{cov}(X,aY+bZ) = a\,\textrm{cov}(X,Y)+b\,\textrm{cov}(X,Z).$$

If you want to calculate all the betas at once, you can do so in matrix form.
$$
\beta = \frac{\Sigma w}{w^T\Sigma w}
$$

Comment: This calculation is a component of the formula for Contribution to Value at Risk in Finance. If you take the derivative of weighted standard deviation, then the result is the element-wise product of this beta vector and the weights.